# Eclipse Scout Table Menu depend on table context

Tags: contextmenu, eclipse-scout

What is the best way to do "context aware" menu for table in Eclipse scout.

For example, lets assume that table has boolean row "`Additional`", and we want :

if Additional is true show menu :

```
Edit
Add
Additional
```

if false

```
Edit 
Add
Delete
```

How to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Eclipse Scout 4 and newer:
What you want is to override `execOwnerValueChanged(Object)` on your menu items. You will be passed a `List<ITableRow>` as argument with which you can decide if the menu item should be visible/enabled.

I'd suggest you create 2 menu items for Delete and Additional and then implement the solution above.

See also the wiki page in the [Scout Eclipsepedia.](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/HowTo/4.0/Hide_or_disable_menu_items_dynamically)

Comment: See also this discussion on the Eclipse Scout Forum: [execAboutToShow()](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=914212&goto=1556463&#msg_1556463)